# CSS Footer glued to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

i try to create div footer, but have problem.

I have few div blocks located one by one inside container.
Container have 100% height.
Inside Container First Div have 100px height (header).
Second Div (Mainbody) need to have all height up to site bottom (bootom part of screen size) or more.

Third Div have absolute position and located on bottom. 
But summary height of Container Div is more than 100% because i see scroll on right part of page. 
How to resolve this?

Page with css: height:100% takes more than 100%

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container {
  position:relative;
  min-height:100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.header {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

.mainbody {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
}

.footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <p>
      header
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="mainbody">
      <p>
      mainbody
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>
      footer
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried `position:fixed` for the footer?

Comment: This sounds like you want the footer glued to the bottom of the page? If so Google `sticky footer` there's a few ways to do this

Answer (score 0):

Open with your browser. It doesn't show any scroll bars as shown in this snippet. Set

```
.container{ height:100%}
```

rather than

```
min-height:100%
```

as it will exceed the page full size.

Answer (score 0):

You might try `position:fixed; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; height:somevalue;` for the `footer` element, and for the `body` element, also add `padding-bottom:somevalue`(somevalue is the same value for body's padding-bottom and for footer's height)

Answer (score 0):

A dirty solution for your html margins. I've added a `margin-top` property to your html, body css. Now there is no scrollbar on the right.

It seems like `margin: 0;` has no effect on `margin-top` property. I've read online that some browsers tend to set margins by default on certain elements like `body`. I've given you a really dirty solution that may not work well with responsive design.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: -8px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```